# Binary tree implementation - the numbers on the branch are getting replaced

Tags: c++

Following is a Simple binary tree code in C++ that I am trying to implement but the values are getting replaced when i run the code.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class bst
{
private:
    struct node
    {
        int data;
        node *left;
        node *right;
    };
public:
    node *start = NULL;

    node* create_node(node*p,int a)
    {

        if (p == NULL)
        {
            node *n1 = new node;
            n1->data = a;
            n1->left = NULL;
            n1->right = NULL;
            return n1;
        }

        else
        {
            if (a > p->data)
            {
                p->right = create_node(p->right, a);
            }
            else if(a < p->data)
            {
                p->left = create_node(p->left, a);
            }
        }

    }

};

int main()
{
    bst l1;
    int a[10] = { 12, 4, 3, 9, 6, 5, 10, 13, 34, 23 };
    l1.start=l1.create_node(l1.start,a[0]);
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        l1.create_node(l1.start, a[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Could anyone please point out where am i going wrong with it.
When I do an Inorder traversal, my output is 10 12 23. 
When I follow through the code with break points, I see that the numbers under each branch getting replaced.

Comment: Is your compiler not giving you warnings/errors about missing return value from create_node?

Comment: Your `create_node` returns *what*, again? Look at the code closely. If your compiler is *not* giving you a warning similar to: `main.cpp:44:5: Control may reach end of non-void function`, you seriously need to turn up your warning levels. If it *is* giving you that warning, fix it (and any other warnings) *after* fully-understanding what they *mean*.

Comment: I don't see if this code is wrong. I strongly suspect that your inorder function is wrong. I went ahead and tested the code and it works all fine. Can you share your inorder code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My Inorder Function is :

```
void printInorder(node* node)
    {
        if (node == NULL)
            return;


        printInorder(node->left);

        printf("%d ", node->data);

        printInorder(node->right);
    }
```

I found the issue , The change that made it work was something similar to what Vallabh suggested

```
if (a > p->data)
            {
                if (p->right == NULL)
                {
                    p->right = create_node(p->right, a);
                }
                else
                {
                    create_node(p->right, a);
                }
            }
```